# Modal JDialog gets pushed to back when opening another JDialog

Tags: java

Fairly new to Java, and running into a z order problem. I have a legacy Java application that has a main window A, which pops up a modal JDialog B. Upon clicking a button on B, a modal dialog C pops up.

For the transition from B to C:

```
B.setVisible(false);
B.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
B.toFront();
B.repaint();
B.setVisible(true);

.... 
C.pack();
C.setResizable(false);
C.setModal(true);
C.setVisible(true);
```

When C goes away, the opposite is done and B is set as modal again.

This works, except that as soon as C is shown, B is pushed to the back behind A. **I want to keep B in front of A while C is displayed**.

What am I misunderstanding/doing wrong?

Running on Windows 7 64 bit, Java 1.8.0_20-b26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the parent of the C dialog is B and not A.

Comment: Oh my. I feel sheepish. Thanks!